# Alphanumeric regex not working with non-roman characters

Tags: php, regex

I want to *only* have alphanumeric characters [a-f0-9] in a string. To achieve this, I have:

```
$text = preg_replace("/[^[:alnum:]]/u", '', $text);
```

Works fine in this case:

```
$text = 'hello?world'; // becomes 'helloworld'
```

The problem is that it doesn't seem to work for other languages, for example:

```
$text = '日本国'; // becomes '日本国'
```

That should be empty!

[Ideone demo](https://ideone.com/8vOLPA). What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: [a-f0-9] is a *lot* narrower than "alphanumeric", and easily expressed in exactly that form; but that would leave just 'e' from 'hello?world'. The point of special ranges like `[:alnum:]` is that they *do* cover all languages and alphabets, so I'm not really sure what you were trying to achieve.

Comment: @IMSoP Ah I see. So `[:alnum:]` is not specifically for roman-characters? That makes a lot more sense.

Comment: If you want to only keep ASCII letters why don't you just use `$text = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]+/u", '', $text);`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That is the correct answer. I misunderstood `:alnum:` as I outlined in my comment above. Thanks.

Comment: You can remove the unicode flag `/u`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be more clear, by default `[:alnum:]` contains `[a-zA-Z0-9]` (letters and digits from the ASCII range 0-127).
But if you use the u modifier, this class is extended to all UNICODE letters and digits.

The u modifier:

- changes the way the subject string (and the pattern) is read (code point by code point instead of byte by byte)
- extends several<sup>*</sup> character classes to UNICODE characters (<sup>*</sup>as a counter example, the `\h` character class doesn't change.)

It's possible to separate these two behaviors with commands at the start of the pattern:

- `(*UTF)` at the start of the pattern informs that the subject and the pattern have to be read as utf (utf-8 in php) encoded strings (and not byte by byte).
- `(*UCP)` extends the character classes.

*(see several tests [here](https://3v4l.org/1JjdC):)*

So instead of the u modifier, you can write your pattern this way:

```
$str = preg_replace('~(*UTF)[^[:alnum:]]+~', '', $str);
```

You can also choose to not use the `[:alnum:]` class at all and to be more explicit:

```
$str = preg_replace('~[^a-z0-9]+~ui', '', $str);
```

Since there is no predefined character class in the pattern, the `(*UCP)` part of the u modifier doesn't change anything.

---

Obviously, as noted in comments, it's also possible to ignore the fact that your subject string may contain characters out of the ASCII range, and read this string byte by byte with:

```
$str = preg_replace('~[^[:alnum:]]+~', '', $str);

// or

$str = preg_replace('~[^a-z0-9]+~i', '', $str);
```

and it will work too, but IMO it's less rigorous.